# Can you upgrade a C-50 APU to an E-350 on an Aspire Laptop?

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I bought an overpriced laptop with a C-50 processor, here in mexico is like buying a netbook for 550 dollars in the outfit of a laptop.

I was wondering if I could upgrade its cpu and change it for its big brother, the E-350 at 1.6 Ghz. Is it even possible to buy them separately?

The model is a Aspire 5253-BZsomething.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. Laptop CPUs tend to be soldered onto the motherboard, so they're practically nonreplaceable.

Answer (score 2):

Some laptop CPUs are soldered but many are not, in your case both use the same BGA-413 socket so it could be possible, but keep in mind the C50 its a 9W micro while the E350 needs 18W to work.

In the best case you take a hit to your battery life